# How to prevent Excel change automatically text to date?

Tags: excel

Excel always automatically change my data source into date once imported, which drives me crazzzzzy.

Here is the issue:
My data source stores combinations in a form of #-#-#, eg. 1-2-3.
Whenever I imported the data to Excel, Excel automatically changed it to 1/02/2003.
If I format the column, it returns some random numbers, for instance 37653 for 1-2-3.
Could anyone please inform me how to the keep the #-#-# without turning to date or random numbers.

Cheers,

Aaron

Comment: The random numbers are the internal way Excel stores dates, i.e. the number 43794 is Nov 25 2019 formatted as "General". How exactly are you bringing the data into Excel? Open a file? Copy and paste? A query?

Comment: If you are importing the data, as you write, you need to designate that particular column as `Text`.

Comment: Always help to describe exactly how you're getting your data into Excel.